# C code works in 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 but fails in 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count = 0;

int * new_array() {
    int i, *array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 9);

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        array[i] = count++;

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return array;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int *a;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = new_array();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine in 64-bit and the output is as expected.

However, in 32-bit, the output turns out to be:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

And the error message appears：

```
prog: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

I don't understand why. As I'm concerned， it also should fail in 64-bit, since I only allocated 9 integer-size but accessed the 10th element of array. If this is the case, why I should care about the length? I can just give a random number as the length.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc()`. See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Do you have any idea how much memory you're leaking?

Comment: You are expecting _undefined behaviour_ to behave defined! Seen any nasal daemons recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could deterministically expect a certain behavior when you invoke undefined behavior, it wouldn't be undefined. Your problem is found here:

> the output is as expected

In addition to that core problem with array-out-of bounds access because you didn't alloc 10 items, your program also have the following issues:

Bugs

- You never free any memory and for each call to the function, you create a memory leak. You should also check the result from malloc.

Code style/bad practice

- Avoid using `new_array()` function declarations in C. It means "accept anything" as parameter. This is an obsolete feature of C which may be removed from the language. Instead, define your function as `int * new_array (void)`
- Don't use global variables. `count` could be declared as a local static variable inside the function, or better yet, pass it as a parameter to the function.
- [Casting the result of malloc is harmless but also pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538350/584518).

You would likely benefit from a modern C11 compiler. It looks like you are still writing old C90 code.

Answer (score 4):

As you're allocating memory for only `9` elements in the `malloc()` call but  later, with the returned pointer,  you're writing

```
for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    array[i] = count++;
```

which is actually an [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) scenario and essentially accssing memory out of bounds, creating  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, the output of UB is UB, it has nothing to do with `32` or `64` bit architecture.

That said, always check for the success of `malloc()` by testing its return value against NULL, before making use of the returned pointer directly.

Also, please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

> As I'm concerned， it also should fail in 64-bit, since I only allocated 9 integer-size but accessed the 10th element of array.

Which leads to *undefined behavior*, which could mean an immediate segfault *or* run to completion with no apparent issues *or* corrupting your program state such that a failure occurs later on, etc.

This one of many areas where the language won't protect you from yourself.